# how to solve useEffect infinite loop and circular dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

We are trying to remove the circular dependency and infinite loop, how can we achieve this on below code.

We don't want to clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), so we are not passing an empty array ([]) as a second argument.

```
const [isBoolean, setIsBoolean] = useState(false); 
const [isBool, setIsBool] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    setIsBoolean(true);
    setIsBool(true);
}, [isBoolean])

useEffect(() => {
     setIsBoolean(true);
     setIsBool(true);
}, [isBool])
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, both useEffects are same, and they get triggered with every setState

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid the infinite loop. But it would be better to have the finality.
Namely that the code is reexecuted at each set and that we enter a use effect if in the last loop, one of the values put in the table has been changed.

```js
const [isBoolean, setIsBoolean] = useState(false); 
const [isBool, setIsBool] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!isBoolean && !isBool) {
      setIsBoolean(true);
      setIsBool(true);
    }
}, [isBoolean])

useEffect(() => {
    if (!isBoolean && !isBool) {
      setIsBoolean(true);
      setIsBool(true);
    }
}, [isBool])
```